# Vertical Segmented Control iOS

Tags: ios, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

I need to write a custom vertical segmented control for iOS. In the control, I can specify a list of items, each item has an image icon and a text label (with font, color, selected color, etc) that appears immediately below the image icon (the text label is not constant, it will be changing too frequently). I thought of using UIButton for the item, but the problem is I don't know how to specify placement of text and image in UIButton. Am I missing something obvious? Otherwise, what is the cleanest way to implement this segmented control.

Answer (score 1):

I would go for a custom view based on a `UIStackView`. Your `UIStackView` would have `.fill` alignment and `.fillEqually` distribution. Each segmented item could be a direct subview of your `UIStackView`. Your view hierarchy would be in something like: 
[image]

Of course you need this to be done on code if you're segmented have dynamic content. Also, you need to add gesture recognizers so your custom segmented can change state.

And here's the result:

[image]